# Inspecting Source in Chrome DevTools in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

Working with create-react-app, while **npm start** is running, if I inspect an app, in Chrome DevTools I can find my project files only inside the **Webpack-internal** folder. Is that normal?

Further more if I open Source tab, this is what I see:

[image]

It seems that the ES6 code is changed to ES5 and also there are **__source:** tags every where.

I thought if I disable SourceMap for JavaScript in my DevTools settings, those **__source** tags will disappear, they didn't. Even refreshing the browser or relaunching the Dev server with npm start, didn't remove them.

This make it very hard debuggin the code. Are you facing the same issue? Any solution?

Comment: yes that is totally normal and the way it works. if you check [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) will get what is happening. and for debugging you are taking wrong path, it is better to install [React-Dev-Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) and debug from your editor. VSCode is the best for that reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Babel` is part of the build process, it is responsible for transpiling ES6 into ES5 so your app can work on browsers that don't support ES6 properly.

You can read more about it here https://babeljs.io/

You won't really be able to see your precompiled code in the browser. You should use an extension called `React Developer Tools`, you can get it for Chrome here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

With the extension you can see much more relevant information about your React app.

Comment: More relevant? What about setting breakpoints and debugging? As far as I can see React Developer Tools just shows the currently rendered state, which is great too